# “invalid tar magic” on OpenWRT

Tags: tar, openwrt, archive

I'm trying to install JavaSE on a OpenWrt (Pandorabox) device. When I run

```
tar -xvf ejdk-8u65-linux-arm-sflt.tar.gz
```

I get `tar: invalid tar magic`.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps that version of `tar` doesn't automatically recognize `gzip` files, try adding `-z` to the command

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The version of tar on OpenWRT is a smaller one than the one on full-blown systems, designed to fit small devices (it's [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/).) To keep small, it lacks features such as the automatic detection of compressed archives.

Try declaring the compression format manually with the `-z` option:

```
tar -xvzf ejdk-8u65-linux-arm-sflt.tar.gz
```

Support for gzip in the `tar` utility is an optional feature that may or may not be enabled on OpenWRT. If you don't have it, call `zcat` (or `gzip -dc`) explicitly:

```
zcat ejdk-8u65-linux-arm-sflt.tar.gz | tar -xvf -
```

Comment: Both commands stopped when extracting: `ejdk1.8.0_65/linux_arm_sflt/jre/lib/rt.jar` with another `tar: invalid tar magic`

Comment: @Toc Are you sure the file is undamaged and compete? Were there any other errors? Do you have a URL for the file so we can check?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/index.html Unfortunately I had to register to download the file (whose name is in the opening question). Thank you.

Comment: Using a zip utility in Windows I recognized that `rt.jar` is the last file in the tar archive. Maybe the `invalid tar magic message` is only an irrelevant warning?

Comment: @Toc Damn. Sorry, I'm not going to create an account for this. Does `rt.jar` have the right size after extraction? This message indicates that something about the format of the tar file isn't supported, but this may well be harmless trailing garbage.

Comment: I've verified the files extracted under Linux and the ones extracted under Windows. No difference. I hope and I think all is well done. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when extracting an archive, finally I upgraded `tar` and it solved the problem.

```
opkg update
opkg upgrade tar
```