# How to solve “tar: invalid magic” error on Linux Alpine

Tags: tar, alpine-linux

I'm installing sqlite on Alpine Linux. I download `sqlite-autoconf-3130000.tar.gz` but `tar` could not open it. I tried this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249353/invalid-tar-magic-on-openwrt) but it's not working. `tar` gives this message:

```
tar: invalid magic
tar: short read
```

I wrote these commands.

```
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-autoconf-3090100.tar.gz
tar -zxvf sqlite-autoconf-3090100.tar.gz
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer with the command (and its arguments) that you tried to run.

Comment: Did the download complete successfully? If it did, `ls -l sqlite-autoconf-3090100.tar.gz` should tell you that the file is 2284128 bytes in size.

Comment: Also, is it currently a gzip formatted file? Some browsers do on the fly decompression, meaning that it might still named sqlite-autoconf-3090100.tar.gz but that the contents might actually be sqlite-autoconf-3090100.tar.  No idea if wget does equally smart things, but it is easily tested by leaving of the `z` flag from tar.

Answer (score 43):

Try to install the tar package (apk add tar). Busybox tar (default) doesn't support all features.

Comment: I ran into the same issue when running a tar command in a Dockerfile and installing tar worked for me. It's kind of confusing because if you run the command in the shell in the container, it works. But not if it's a RUN command in the Dockerfile without having installed tar first. :|

Answer (score 35):

This doesn't necessarily mean the Alpine version of `tar` is incompatible, as Francesco pointed out you should really check your file checksums.

I ran into this while doing a `curl https://github.com/someproject/releases/project-1.1.0.gz | tar -xvzf` in my Dockerfile.

It turns out what I had forgotten was that `curl` will only follow redirects if you allow it with `-L`, and so it was never getting to the actual file, it was literally downloading the html telling it there was a redirect. Adding the `-L` allowed me to save the file without bloating my container with a new `tar` (beyond the "bloat" added by `curl`).

Comment: This is in fact the correct answer.

Comment: Not really, since it didn't work. We tried it with a -L and still gets the same error.

Comment: In my case the URL had an environment variable that I forgot to set so instead of downloading a tar.gz I downloaded an HTML error page, which failed the tar extraction.

Answer (score 1):

if you use alpine in docker, please assert that you use `COPY` instead of `ADD` in your container file (`Dockerfile`) since `ADD` will decompress on building the layer

alpine default tar **doesn't** give you the hint

```
tar (child): sqlite-autoconf-3090100.tar.gz: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar (child): At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 1):

For me using the other compression format helped.

Compression format in some distros, has to be given explicitly for the tar utility.
In the command, tar -zxvf instead of -z try using following formats.

```
-Z      (De)compress using compress
-z      (De)compress using gzip // this one we are already using in above case
-J      (De)compress using xz
-j      (De)compress using bzip2
-a      (De)compress using lzma
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

tar:invalid magic means that the file is corrupted.

Please check the md5sum if matches...this is what i got:

```
 md5sum  sqlite-autoconf-3090100.tar.gz 
 74931054399a2d7acf35637efe8d6f45  sqlite-autoconf-3090100.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and solved it, however I'm not sure you are facing the same issue.

Code that **Caused error**:

```
wget www.example.com/file.tar.gz
tar -zxvf file.tar.gz
```

Code that **resolved** it:

```
wget https://www.example.com/file.tar.gz
tar -zxvf file.tar.gz
```

Notice that I had forgoten the "https://" wherein the file did get downloaded but the tar gave me the same error. If the file is not found make sure you use

> docker build **--no-cache** ...

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove option `z` which is not available, so instead of

```
tar -zxvf sqlite-autoconf-3090100.tar.gz
```

use

```
tar -xvf sqlite-autoconf-3090100.tar.gz
```

Unzipping will work nevertheless.